# Retrofit2 post request returns 500 error but postman works well

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, http-status-code-500

I've tried many solutions on Stackoverflow. but not work..
please help me...

Retrofit2 POST request returns 500 error. but postman works well.
but If i changed property name of Jsonobject, works well. postman too.
Detail below.

I asked the server team, but they said there was no problem.
So can you check if there is a problem with my code?

## Interface

`interface LoginService {

```
@POST("api/v1/login") // POST
fun requestLogin( // Input
    @Body loginData: JsonObject
): Call<LoginResponse> // Output`
```

## LoginActivity

`class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var viewBinding : ActivityLoginBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
viewBinding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(viewBinding.root)

```
    // client
    val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    clientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    clientBuilder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true)

    // retrofit
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("secret")
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(clientBuilder.build()) // client 
        .build()
    val userid =  viewBinding.idt.text.toString()
    val password = viewBinding.pwdt.text.toString()

    val login = JsonObject()
    login.addProperty("userId", userid)
    login.addProperty("password", password)
    val loginService = retrofit.create(LoginService::class.java)

    viewBinding.signinbtn.setOnClickListener {
        loginService.requestLogin(login).enqueue(object: Callback<LoginResponse>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val responseData = response.body()
                    if (responseData != null) {
                        Log.d("Retrofit","ResponseCode: ${responseData.code} Message: ${responseData.message}")

                        if (responseData.code == 1000) {
                            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, CalendarActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                        }

                        if (responseData.code != 1000) {
                            cuDialog(viewBinding.root, responseData.message)
                        }

                        if (responseData.code == 1000 && viewBinding.auto.isChecked) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.w("Retrofit", "Response Not Successful ${response.code()}")
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("Retrofit","Error!",t)
                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@LoginActivity)
                dialog.setTitle("오류")
                dialog.setMessage("서버와 통신에 실패했습니다.")
                dialog.show()
            }
        })
    }`
```

## data class (Response)

`data class LoginResponse( val isSuccess: Boolean, val code: Int, val message: String, val result: ArrayList<Info>)`

## error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c68F.jpg)

## IN Postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdG2l.png)

postman works well

But what's even more strange is that if I change the name of the property randomly, it responds well. Below is an example.

`val login = JsonObject() login.addProperty("sdfsfssdfd", userid) login.addProperty("sfsfdsfsd", password)`

I changed this part. property name is random.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfhJY.png)

In AndroidStudio, works well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOqBF.png)
of course, postman works well too.

why if Property name is "userId", not working?
please help me..

Comment: "I asked the server team, but they said there was no problem" -- the server is returning a 500 and an "Internal Server Error" response. It is the server team's job to tell you why your request is returning that response. In your screenshot, your login request has empty strings for the user and password, which is a wonderful thing for a screenshot posted to Stack Overflow. However, if your request really is that, empty strings probably are invalid values. In Postman, you have non-empty strings for your user and password.

Comment: Oh my god,,, I missed the blank parameters. very very thank you. I'm sorry to the server team. haha,,

Answer (score 0):

From your side userId and password parameters are blank. I have seen on your error screenshot.

Try to Log your userId and password.

```
val userid =  viewBinding.idt.text.toString() // I think issue is here
val password = viewBinding.pwdt.text.toString() // I think issue is here 
login.addProperty("userId", userid) 
login.addProperty("password", password)
```

Comment: very thank you. I missed that. I tried again and succeeded. very very thank you